# Trying to access json-server data via a controller and factory in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, controller, factory

I'm writing a very simple test app in angular js and am trying to display data stored on a json server to display in the view.

db.json is as follows:

```
{
  "examples": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "example 0",
      "description": "Example 0 description."
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "example 1",
      "description": "Example 1 description."
    }
  ]
}
```

controller is as follows:

```
angular.module('my_app')

.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', 'exampleFactory', function ($scope, exampleFactory) {

    $scope.example = exampleFactory.query({
        })
        .$promise.then(
            function (response) {
                var examples = response;
                $scope.message = examples;
            },
            function (response) {
                $scope.message = "Error: " + response.status + " " + response.statusText;
            }
        );

}])
```

factory is as follows:

```
.factory('exampleFactory', ['$resource', 'baseURL', function ($resource, baseURL) {

        return $resource(baseURL + "examples/:id", null, {
            'update': {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        });
}])
;
```

And view is as follows:

```
<p>Test outside repeat: {{message}}</p>

<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="example in examples">
       <p>Test in repeat: {{message}}</p>
       <p>{{example.name}}</p>
       <p>{{example.description}}</p>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

The interesting thing here is that the data is being returned by the factory. In the above example the first test (outside the ng-repeat) returns the full set. However, nothing inside ng-repeat shows up.

I've got this working using a slightly different arrangement using a service but it doesn;t seem to be working using a factory.

Does anyone have any idea why this is and could they put me right?

Thanks
Stef

Answer (score 2):

I think you just forgot to assign `$scope.examples`, so the `ng-repeat` had no data to loop over:

```
angular.module('my_app')

.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', 'exampleFactory', function ($scope, exampleFactory) {

    $scope.example = exampleFactory.query({
        })
        .$promise.then(
            function (response) {
                var examples = response;
                $scope.message = examples;
                $scope.examples = examples.examples; // I may be reading the JSON wrong here.
            },
            function (response) {
                $scope.message = "Error: " + response.status + " " + response.statusText;
            }
        );

}])
```

Comment: Thanks 2ps - tried that but it didn't work - I eventually sorted it - see next response for details as i couldn;t get the code to display correctly in this reply :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a factory as you can get the methods inside the factory before the factory has been returned. It's the revealing module pattern, good read here if your interested [JavaScript Design Patterns](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)

```js
angular
  .module('my_app')
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', 'exampleFactory',
    function($scope, exampleFactory) {
      function getMessageList() {
        exampleFactory
          .getMessages()
          .then(function(messages) {
            $scope.examples = messages;
          })
          .catch(function(response) {
            $scope.message = "Error: " + response.status + " " + response.statusText;
          });
      }
      getMessageList();

    }
  ])
  .factory('exampleFactory', ['$http', 'baseURL',function($http, baseURL) {
      function getMessages() {
        return $http
          .get(baseURL)
          .then(function(jsonResp) {
            return jsonResp.data;
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            //handle error if needed
            console.log(error);
          });
      }
      return {
        getMessages: getMessages
      };
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<p>Test outside repeat: {{examples}}</p>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="example in examples">
    <p>Test in repeat: {{message}}</p>
    <p>{{example.name}}</p>
    <p>{{example.description}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks alphapilgrim - I eventually sorted it (see above). Also, am using $resource as opposed to $http so I wouldn't go with your solution but your comments are useful and appreciated ;-) Also, cheers for the link, that's tomorrow's reading sorted ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Eventually sorted it by changing controller as follows:

```
.controller("ExampleController", function($scope, exampleFactory) {
  exampleFactory.query(function(response) {
      $scope.examples = response;

      $scope.examples.$promise.then(
          function (response) {
              var examples = response;
              $scope.message = examples;
          },
          function (response) {
              $scope.message = "Error: " + response.status + " " + response.statusText;
          }
      );

  });
});
```

Probably a little bit clunky and it would be nice to be able to reduce it further but as I'm very new to all this I'll go with this for now.